# Ruby Shoes Button.click code does not execute after assignment of variable?

Tags: ruby, button, click, shoes

I ran into a problem that when I assign a variable button.click body it does not execute rest of the body.

```
Shoes.app do
@b1 = button("Open")
@b1.click{
    file= ask_open_file

    text= file.read
    alert "working?"
}
end
```

In above code alert will not execute but if you move it above the assignment statement it works. Can you help me?

Comment: Let me guess: `file.read` throws an exception? What is in your application log?

Comment: before I was not using shoes just plain ruby and file read worked fine but now i guess it does not. how can i get log?

Comment: Thanks man for guiding me into right direction. I had to do it this way File.read(file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file.read` throws an exception, since `file` is a String. You probably want to read the file:

```
Shoes.app do
  @b1 = button("Open")
  @b1.click{
    file= ask_open_file

    text= File.new(file).read
    puts text
    alert "working?"
  }
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.